# No HTTP methods exported in 'file path'. Export a named export for each HTTP method

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

The problem I'm getting is every time I try any code, I get this error:

> No HTTP methods exported in 'file path'. Export a named export for each HTTP method.

Here's my route.ts file:

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';

const apiKey = "";

// Requires "axios" and "form-data" to be installed (see https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios and https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data)
const axios = require('axios');
const FormData = require('form-data');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const inputPath = 'public/CodeGeneration.jpg';
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('size', 'auto');
formData.append('image_file', fs.createReadStream(inputPath), path.basename(inputPath));

axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://api.remove.bg/v1.0/removebg',
  data: formData,
  responseType: 'arraybuffer',
  headers: {
    ...formData.getHeaders(),
    'X-Api-Key': apiKey,
  },
  encoding: null
})
.then((response: any) => {
  if(response.status != 200) return console.error('Error:', response.status, response.statusText);
  fs.writeFileSync("no-bg.png", response.data);
})
.catch((error: any) => {
    return console.error('Request failed:', error);
});
```

Here's my page.tsx file:

```
"use client";
import { useState } from 'react';

const BackgroundRemovalPage = () => {
  const [file, setFile] = useState<File | null>(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [resultPath, setResultPath] = useState<string | null>(null);

  const handleFileChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length > 0) {
      setFile(event.target.files[0]);
    } else {
      console.warn('No files selected');
    }
  };

  const handleUpload = async () => {
    if (!file) return;

    setLoading(true);

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('size', 'auto');
    formData.append('image_file', file);

    try {
      const response = await fetch('/api/backgroundRemover', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
      });

      if (response.ok) {
        const data = await response.json();
        setResultPath(data.path);
      } else {
        console.error('Upload failed:', response.statusText);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="file" accept="image/*" onChange={handleFileChange} />
      <button onClick={handleUpload} disabled={!file || loading}>
        {loading ? 'Processing...' : 'Remove Background'}
      </button>
      {resultPath && <img src={resultPath} alt="Result" />}
    </div>
  );
};

export default BackgroundRemovalPage;
```

I've tried using different API's, tried creating components and calling them in, tried got ChatGPT to rewrite it for me to see if that spots any issues.

Don't know what's causing it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `route.ts` file is incorrect. You need to define a [Route Handler](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers) inside it, like:

```
export async function GET(request: Request) {
 // your application logic
}
```

> The following HTTP methods are supported: GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, HEAD, and OPTIONS. If an unsupported method is called, Next.js will return a 405 Method Not Allowed response.
>
> https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers